# rails javascript i18n specific yml using i18n-js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

My question is if there is anyway to configure i18n-js so that only one specific .yml file is being look up by the javascript but not all. I have followed the example in below links and had the javascript looking up the correct key;However, when I look at the translation.js that this plug in generated in inspect element, All the translation key shows up. We worried that this would be an issue as our app grow since the javascript only needs to know the translation key that it needs. I was thinking to just have a config/locales/en/javascript.yml to put all translation for the javascript in here.

Followed the example

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

http://blog.10to1.be/rails/2011/03/22/localizing-javascript-in-your-rails-app/

ran

```
rake i18n:js:setup
```

application.js

```
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
```

application.html.haml

```
 = javascript_include_tag 'translation'
```

directory

```
|config
|-locales
|--en
|---en.yml
|---javascript.yml   <------ that's what I want and the js only look at this one2
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can specify a specific key. I'm having issues getting the translations.js file to update, so I can't verify that this actually works, but the documentations says it:

Inside config/i18n-js.yml

```
translations:
- file: "app/assets/javascripts/application/i18n/translations.js"
  only: '*.js*'
```

Inside en.yml

```
  js:
    posts:
      select2:
        placeholder: 'Please, select tags'
        no-matches: 'No tags found'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way of doing that through simple configuration.

`i18n-js` is agnostic of any YML translation files or translation folders (such as Rails' default `config/locales`). It just asks the `i18n` gem (which ships with Rails) to retrieve all available translations and then it export them to a JS format.

You could however define a custom rails environment, say `js_i18n`, in which you overwrite the default i18n load path as such:

```
# config/environments/js_i18n.rb
# code similar to the rest of your config files - you could copy `development.rb`
# ...
config.i18n.load_path = Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'js', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

And then use this environment which will load only YML/Ruby files under `config/locales/js` to run whatever task you like, such as:

```
RAILS_ENV=js_i18n rake i18n:js:export
```